# Correctly waiting for process to finish

Tags: elixir

Currently I have something like this:

```
ref = Process.monitor(worker)

receive do
  {:DOWN, ^ref, :process, ^worker, :normal} ->
    IO.puts("Normal exit from #{inspect(worker)}")

  {:DOWN, ^ref, :process, ^worker, msg} ->
    IO.puts("Received :DOWN from #{inspect(worker)}")
end
```

That worker have a start_link which send a stream of data into a consumer, all this happens inside a mix task, so if I dont add the receive do, as soon as the mix dies, it also kills the children process, same way as if I run it from a iex -S mix shell.

```
flow
... some producer consumer in the middle
|> Flow.into_specs(consumer)
```

The thing is, when the flow is empty (is a finite flow), the worker doesnt seem to die, the receive do doesnt get triggered, is there any other way to achieve this?

Edit:

Testing with a dummy process I dont even need `receive do`

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Stuff do


  def run([]) do
    {:ok, worker} = Worker.start_link([])
  end
end

defmodule Worker do

  def start_link([]) do
    Enum.map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], fn number ->
      IO.puts "COUNTING"
      Process.sleep(1000)
      IO.puts "-----------"
    end)
  end
end
```

But when the worker launches a Flow, if I dont wait with `receive do` it instantly dies as soon as I execute the task, so maybe that's the issue.

Comment: When the flow is empty it should return immediately, faster than your process goes to `receive`. Could you please `|> IO.inspect` of what `Process.monitor(worker)` returns?

Comment: ref is just a pid

Comment: The worker is started like this; {:ok, worker} = Worker.start_link([]) then ref = Process.monitor(worker)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on [`Process.monitor/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Process.html#monitor/1):

> If the process is already dead when calling `Process.monitor/1`, a `:DOWN` message is delivered immediately.

That said when the `Flow` is empty the `receive do` sets handlers for `:DOWN` message *after* it was delivered. To handle the case one should swap the calls and prepare message handlers *before* starting to monitor the process.

```
receive do
  {:DOWN, ref, :process, ^worker, msg} ->
    case [retrieve_ref(), msg] do
      [^ref, :normal] ->
        IO.puts("Normal exit from #{inspect(worker)}")
      [^ref, msg] ->
        IO.puts("Received :DOWN from #{inspect(worker)}")
    end
end

ref = Process.monitor(worker)
store_ref_somewhere_ets_or_agent_or_whatever(ref)
```

I assume `store_ref_somewhere_ets_or_agent_or_whatever/1` and respective `retrieve_ref/0` would be easy to implement.

Comment: How would you define msg beforehand? it can be :normal and :DOWN?

Comment: Pattern matching in lines 4 and 6 distinguishes between these two. It can be [`:normal`, `:noproc`, and `:noconnection`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2) btw.

Comment: I am testing it (using :ets) but it doesnt stop the process, I mean, exit the mix task, it gets stuck after all the finite flow has been consumed

Comment: Actually I am debugging this:     receive do something -> require IEx; IEx.pry   end and nothing is reaching, it doesnt get triggered

Comment: Like if Flow didnt send any message when finishing

Comment: Wait a second. `Flow` won’t send anything, you should explicitly terminate the `Worker` since it is monitored. `Worker.stop` probably should do.

Comment: Cant it be explicitly killed in the consumer which is consuming the Flow events? or how do you know it already finished and then you have to kill it?

Comment: Sure it can be explicitly killed. The thing is you have to terminate the process you are monitoring to receive the `:DOWN` message.

Comment: do you know if its possible to listen for completion in handle_info/2 of the consumer? something like :done or :halted

Comment: The things is in the consumer I dont know when it has finished, I dont receive more empty events or anything like that, it just stops consuming but I havent any callback for that

Comment: Set a timeout on an interval between incoming messages and terminate if it increases the preset value? I am not sure I completely got the architecture.